# Erase a character from a string vector in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, stl

I'm trying to implement an undo function for a very simple text editor. Currently, I have a std::vector that stores a user-entered string for a specific row that acts as the current line number the user is on.

I was able to insert a character into the current string by using this code:

```
void Editor::insertCharacter(char& c)
{
    lines[row].insert(column, 1, c);
    column++;
}
```

In this case, I insert the character into the current row, at a specific column. This column acts as an index to where the cursor is supposed to be,  so by doing `column++`, the cursor moves one position to the right, after inserting the character. This method works fine. The problem I'm having now is when I'm trying to undo inserting a character.

Basically, I have to erase the character where `column` is currently located, then decrement `column` to achieve an "undo"

The first thing I tried to do was deleting the character like this:

```
lines[row].erase(column)
```

Here is an example of what happens when I run this (where | is the cursor position):

```
hello|     (user enters hello)
h|ello     (user moves cursor back to column 2)
hTEST|ello (user enters the word TEST)
(user hits ctrl + z which triggers undo)
hTES|      (final output)
```

So, I looked online and saw that I could use an iterator + an offset to delete an index of a variable. So I updated the undo function to look like this:

`lines[row].erase(lines.begin() + column)`

But this doesn't compile, and I get this error:

```
error: no matching member function for call to
      'erase'
    lines[row].erase(lines.begin() + column);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

So how should I erase this single part of the string without erasing everything remaining in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be: `lines[row].erase(lines[row].begin() + column)`

Comment: Oh my god kill me please. Yep that was it.